# RemoteCertificateNameMismatch in RemoteCertificateValidationCallback method while connecting SMPT server with ssl enabled configuration

Tags: ssl, smtp, smtpclient

H All,

SMPT communication is not working with enabled SSL configuration.

I am sending email through SMTP and it is working perfect. But When I enabled SSL and after that it is not working and got the error in RemoteCertificateValidationCallback (callback method) and description is - RemoteCertificateNameMismatch  and Certificate Chain Error .

SO I have bypassed this error by returning True in RemoteCertificateValidationCallback but as we know it is not recommended in Production environment.

Then I downloaded the SSL certificate from SMPT server (for PORT 25) using OPENSSL command and installed certificate in Trusted Root and attached this certificate in SmtpClient.ClientCertificates.

Code Below:

*SmtpClient SmtpClient= new SmtpClient(address)

SmtpServer.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);*

I tested the code again and Interestingly my second error gone and got got only first error ie - RemoteCertificateNameMismatch  in RemoteCertificateValidationCallback block. 
Can you please help me here .

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Abdul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution and Thank for MSDN :)

I have changed SMTP server name as Certificate Name (which mentioned as CN attribute in Certificate) and it is working.

Regards
Abdul